# Python https-proxy request Entsoe

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch data from Entsoe's transparency web-API on my server which is behind a proxy. However, when I run the following code I keep getting a bad handshake error. The web-API does connect from the browser.

```
import requests
url='https://transparency.entsoe.eu/api'
proxies = {'http':'172.26.28.25:8080', 'https':'172.26.28.25:8080'}
requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
```

I keep getting error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='transparency.entsoe.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api?... (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",),))
```

How can I solve this error?

Kind regards,
Matthijs Toorenburg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initiate an API call you should supply the request parameters too.
W/o an API token [Rejected TP request](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/web%20api/Guide.html#_rejection_of_request) you'd only get Unauthorized (HTTP: 401).

You should also keep in mind, that the TP allows only a limited number of requests posted from a single IP within a specific timeframe. Id. [TP query limits](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/web%20api/Guide.html#_query_limits)

In other cases, you address the host of the API, without acutally initiating an API call
(you could use [API Tester](https://apitester.com/shared/checks/28a192d31fba4d7790260c54af303417) as a toy example).